# Need help conceptualizing a blockchain industry 4.0 project

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Like the title suggest, I need help.
I've little experience with the blockchain, mainly a simple ERC20 token projet I did a few months ago.

Now for my bachelor thesis, i was asked the following :

1. Develop one or several smart contract(s) to trace the origin of the product and its
   conformity certifications / administrative attributes and behaviours.
2. Register the product on the blockchain and deploy a validation scheme to protect it
   against counterfeit
3. Protect the production method (recipe) as an IPR

The said "product" in this refers mainly to manufactured pieces, like a watch piece.
This project is a proof of concept more than anything else so I have no real pieces. I have to create a mockup of what could be used in a manufacture.

Now I was wondering what to use to achieve this goal. Are NFTs are a good option to insure each piece's conformity or should it be used only for the final product or else ?

I don't know all the possibilities of the technology, thus why I'm asking for help.

Any leads to what to use or tutorials would be more than welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Company "emertech" already have such blockchain products (anti-counterfeit and logging), see their site: https://emertech.hk/en/

Comment: This question not good fit for StackOverflow Q&A format, because what you basically need is consulting service that understand the problem and can help you out. The scope of this problem is worth of 100 page document.

Comment: Yeah i know my question isn't exactly a good fit fo SO but I didn't know where else to ask since most ethereum forums i came accross seemed dead.
And yeah a 50-100 page document is propably what I have to produce in this project. Maybe someone could indicate me a better place to ask my question ?